# Angular 2: ng2-bootstrap panelClass not working on panels

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

According to ng2-bootstrap documentation, there's a `panelClass` annotation available for panels. But I can't get it to work.

This is my markup:

```
<accordion>
<accordion-group [panelClass]="panel-primary">
    <div accordion-heading>
        test
    </div>
    test
</accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

But that produces:

```
<accordion-group>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" href="" tabindex="0">
                <!--template bindings={}-->
                <div accordion-heading="">
                    test
                </div>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</accordion-group>
```

I am using ng2-bootstrap v1.1.13.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use simple quote like this : `[panelClass]=" 'panel-primary' "`

Binding is done with string variable. In your case, Angular2 search for a panel-primary attribute and not the litteral string 'panel-primary'.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you sir.

Comment: hey I'm having the same issue and I've tried this solution but haven't been able to get it working ideas?